# Python click, Can you make -h as an alias

Tags: python, python-click

I have recently found the click library (http://click.pocoo.org/6/) and I love it.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to create an alias for the `--help` option which shortcuts to the help. So, for example:

```
app.py --help
```

gives the help for the main app and

```
app.py sub --help
```

will give the help for the sub. I want to be able to use -h as well. If I were creating the option, it may look something like:

```
@click.option('-h', '--help')
```

but the `--help` option is built in. Is there a way to extend that option or create an alias for it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, I found it:

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/documentation/#help-parameter-customization

```
@click.command(context_settings=dict(help_option_names=["-h", "--help"]))
def cli():
    pass
```

Comment: By the way, you can also pass `context_settings` to a group.. just sayin'

Comment: how about -V and --version? any ideas?